# Assert presence of text in an html tag attribute using Puppeteer, Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, html, mocha.js, chai, puppeteer

I'm beginning my journey with these technologies (including Javascript), so, a beginners question.  I'm struggling to work out how to assert that the given text within an HTML attribute is as expected.

The HTML snippet:

```
<input name="8hv3a" type="radio" id="email-optout-8hv3a" value="1|optin|out" data-com.user-edited="yes">
```

Here is my .it function thus far, using Mochai, Puppeteer and Chai (setup and teardown elided for clarity:

```js
  it('opt out of email', async function () {

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout();
        await page.waitForSelector('.widget-title');
        const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe');
        const emailOptOutButton = await frame.$('#email-optout-8hv3a');
        await emailOptOutButton.click();
        const emailOptOutConfirmedValue = await frame.$('#email-optout-8hv3a', e => e.getAttribute('data-com.user-edited'))
        expect(emailOptOutConfirmedValue).to.include('yes')


    })
```

Everything works up until the click event, but my assertion is clearly wrong.  The error is:

```
 AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given
```

I've tried

```
    it('opt out of email', async function () {

    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout();
    await page.waitForSelector('.widget-title');
    const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe');
    const emailOptOutButton = await frame.$('#email-optout-8hv3a');
    await emailOptOutButton.click();
    await page.$eval.emailOptOutConfirmedValue.getAttribute('data-com.user-edited')
    expect(emailOptOutConfirmedValue).to.include('yes')


})
```

Which gives:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

And also:

```
 it('opt out of email', async function () {

    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout();
    await page.waitForSelector('.widget-title');
    const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe');
    const emailOptOutButton = await frame.$('#email-optout-8hv3a');
    await emailOptOutButton.click();
    const emailOptOutConfirmedValue = await frame.$('#email-optout-8hv3a', e => e.getAttribute('data-com.user-edited'))
    assert.equal(emailOptOutConfirmedValue, 'yes')


})
```

Which gives:

```
ReferenceError: assert is not defined
```

As I said, I'm a beginner so go any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked what `console.log( typeof emailOptOutConfirmedValue )` or just `console.log( emailOptOutConfirmedValue )` print out?

Answer (score 4):

This code is wrong:

```
const emailOptOutConfirmedValue = await frame.$('#email-optout-8hv3a', e => e.getAttribute('data-com.user-edited'))
expect(emailOptOutConfirmedValue).to.include('yes')
```

You're using [`frame.$(selector)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameselector). Notice how it takes only one argument. The second argument is ignored and your call returns a handle to a DOM element, which causes the `expect(...).to.include(...)` to fail with a complaint that it cannot test that thing.

You should use [`frame.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)
 instead. This call will call the function passed as a second argument on the result of applying the selector. So the code should be:

```
const emailOptOutConfirmedValue = await frame.$eval('#email-optout-8hv3a', e => e.getAttribute('data-com.user-edited'))
expect(emailOptOutConfirmedValue).to.include('yes')
```

I've left your test intact above, but it seems to me what you'd be looking for here is for a specific value for the attribute, so I'd use this test:

```
expect(emailOptOutConfirmedValue).to.equal('yes')
```

The inclusion test would pass if the attribute's value is `baryesfoo`.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense.  So I changed the code to your suggested.  Now I get a "AssertionError: expected null to equal 'yes'" error so for some reason it can't find my selector. I wonder if getAttribute is the right strategy

Comment: I'd be surprised if the issue is the selector. When you say "selector" what I understand is "CSS selector", which is `#email-optout-8hv3a`. If this selector failed, then puppeteer itself would throw an error, which would be different from the one you mention. The error you get is exactly the one you'd get if your element does *not* have the attribute you are looking for. When you call `element.getAttribute(name)` with a name that names a non-existent attribute, then the return value is `null`, and `null !== "yes"`.

Comment: If the attribute is set by asynchronous code, you may need to structure your test differently. Or you may need to poll the DOM *until* the condition you are testing for is satisfied. Hard to tell which way to go without knowing the whole context for your code.

Comment: You're right.  It turns out the attribute was only present in Chrome but not Chromium when spun up by puppeteer.  So I changed the attribute to assert against and now all good!  thanks for your efforts.